# Getting an error in the Email textbox whenever i try to SignUp using a Site for testing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So whenever i `Click` the SignUp `Button`,the browser shows me this error:

> "Syntax error: Missing operand after '@live' operator."

**And Stack Trace:**

```
> [SyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Missing operand after '@live' operator.]
   System.Data.ExpressionParser.Parse() +2082709
   System.Data.DataExpression..ctor(DataTable table, String expression, Type type) +131
   System.Data.DataTable.Select(String filterExpression) +107
   Class1.Authenticate(String id, String pas) +196
   Class1.add(String Email, String pas, String Name, DateTime SignDate) +205
   SignUp.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +148
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9692746
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +108
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3562
```

**This is my Class Code for the website:**

```
Public Class Class1


Private Shared dsPubs As DataSet

Public dr As DataRow
Public Function Authenticate(ByVal id As String, ByVal pas As String) As Integer

    Dim strConnectionString As String = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Shop;Data Source=."
    Dim instsqlconnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnectionString)

    instsqlconnection.Open()

    Dim daCstmrs As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Customer_Detail", instsqlconnection)
    dsPubs = New DataSet("Customer")
    daCstmrs.Fill(dsPubs, "login")
    instsqlconnection.Close()


    Dim drResult As DataRow() = dsPubs.Tables("login").Select(" EmailAddress = " + id.ToString())

    If (drResult.Length > 0) Then
        If drResult(0)("Password").ToString().Trim() = pas Then

            Return 1
        Else
            Return 2
        End If

    Else
        Return 0
    End If

End Function

Public Function add(ByVal Email As String, ByVal pas As String, ByVal Name As String, ByVal SignDate As Date) As Integer
    Dim strConnectionString As String
    Dim instsqlconnection As SqlConnection
    strConnectionString = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Shop;Data Source=."
    instsqlconnection = New SqlConnection(strConnectionString)
    instsqlconnection.Open()
    Dim daCstmrs As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Customer_Detail", instsqlconnection)
    Dim dsPubs As New DataSet("Customer")
    Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable("login")
    daCstmrs.Fill(dsPubs, "login")
    instsqlconnection.Close()
    Dim a As Integer = Authenticate(Email, pas)
    If (a = 0) Then
        Dim cmdBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(daCstmrs)
        Dim dr As DataRow
        dr = dsPubs.Tables("login").NewRow()
        dr("EmailAddress") = Email
        dr("Password") = pas
        dr("Name") = Name
        dr("DateOBirth") = SignDate
        dsPubs.Tables("login").Rows.Add(dr)
        daCstmrs.Update(dsPubs, "login")
        Return 1
    Else
        Return 2
    End If
End Function
```

And Finally this is the SignUp `button` `OnClick` code:

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim p As New Class1
    Dim y As Integer
    y = p.add(Me.EmailSignUp.Text, Me.PassSignUp.Text, Me.NameSignUp.Text, Me.DobSignUp.Text)
    If (y = 1) Then

        Response.Redirect("CheckOut.aspx")
    Else
        Me.Label6.Text = "add failed "
    End If

End Sub
```

I don't know what i should do to avoid getting the error on the browser and to successfully add the record to the database.I know that there's something about the `'@'` that should be fixed but don't know what.

**After a lot of trying to narrow where my problem is,i found out that my problem is coming from this line:**

```
Dim drResult As DataRow() = dsPubs.Tables("login").Select(" EmailAddress = " + id.ToString())
```

Something related to the id.ToString,it only works if i enter a number,otherwise it keeps showing me an error!

Comment: You ought to select only the columns you need from the database. If you fill a DataTable with the results instead of a DataSet then you will not have to have to use `.Tables("login")`. You should store a hashed and salted password, never plain text - there are plenty of web pages which show how. You could have queried the database for the password column for that email address, using a parameterised query, thus not needing a DataTable/Set. Finally, as it is, you need single quotes around the `id` string.

Comment: i added single quotes around id but it isn't working,can you tell me how can i get it to work,it works great when i put numbers but not anything else.

Comment: It would help if you updated your question to add your new version of that line, is it `Dim drResult As DataRow() = dsPubs.Tables("login").Select("EmailAddress = '" & id & "'")`? What is the error now? (Please edit your question to add this information.)

Comment: I had a mistype,i fixed it now and it is working,Thank You!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Andrew Morton said , adding single quotes around id string will fix the problem!

> Dim drResult As DataRow() = dsPubs.Tables("login").Select("
>   EmailAddress = " + id.ToString())

Will become :

> Dim drResult As DataRow() =
>   dsPubs.Tables("login").Select("EmailAddress = '" & id & "'")